# Angular setting a selected attribute with ng-options

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-select

Im populating the values and display names for a select based on a JSON call. In the same call, I'm pulling from a nested array to get a default account value (if it exists). 
so I have a scope that is holding that default account value, and the select is populating, but for the life of me, I can't figure out how to get the select attribute to apply to the object in the array that has a value that corresponds to the default value.

Essentially, I just want to apply "selected" to the option if the default account ID exists in the array.

Additionally, I cannot change the ng-model of the select because its tied into the form collection function.

Also, Im open to using ng-repeat vs ng-options, just couldn't figure it out with repeat so I moved to the options paradigm.

Any assistance would be grateful!
HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" id="authQAccount" name="authQAccount" ng-model="authFields.accountID" ng-init ng-options="item as item.name for item in accounts track by item.ID" ng-selected="$scope.defaultAcct" required>
    </select>
```

In my controller:

```
$http.get('/api/assessment/authorize').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.content = data.data;
    //Pop the defaults and user options
    $scope.languages = [];
    angular.forEach(data.data.languages, function(value, key) {
          $scope.languages.push(value);
    });
    $scope.accounts = [];
    angular.forEach(data.data.accounts, function(value, key) {
          $scope.accounts.push(value);

    }); 

    $scope.defaultAcct = data.data.defaultAccount;
```

The data Im getting:

```
"data": {
    "defaultAccount": "6481004",
    "defaultLanguage": "en_us",
    "defaultAddonBody": "Test Email for Default",
    "accounts": [{
        "ID": "6481004",
        "name": " ABC Company, Inc.            "
    }, {
        "ID": "6481619",
        "name": "EDF Company - Personal                "
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-selected` only works on `option` elements and not on the `select` element itself. I don't think you can achieve what you want here with `ng-options`, if `ng-model` isn't set to a matching item then there's no way for the `select` to have that item selected.

Unless you only want it to *appear* selected, then you can add `<option value="" ng-if="defaultAccount">{{defaultAccountName}}</option>`. But then you'd have 2 items for the same value, you could either remove the default account from the list of options or keep the two items but with one of them prefixed as `(Default)`. The second option lets users still select the default option without losing their choice later on, in case the default changes. This also means your form has the default selected without having to change the outer model.

Comment: Thanks Scott! I had left in the ng-options on the select just to illustrate what I was trying to do, but this is exactly the confirmation I was looking for. Thanks!